# Extract field from a row and do math using awk

Tags: awk

I have a df output from solaris host from which I need to display only required ones and also want to do math (subtraction) between two values and display the output of that.

```
bash-2.03# df -t /fsystem
/fsystem          (filer:/vol/volname/filesys): 3790340712 blocks 14310983 files
                                  total: 21616671840 blocks 30443110 files
bash-2.03#
```

Expected output:

```
/fsystem  filer:/vol/volname/filesys 16132127
```

where  16132127 is the output of subtraction (30443110 - 14310983). 
Prefer to do this in one line of an awk script.

I am able to extract the required values from below command but not able to do the math and get the preferred output.

bash-2.03# df -t /fsystem | awk '(NR==1){print $1" "$2" "$5}(NR==2){print $4}'

/fsystem (filer:/vol/volname/filesys):  14310983

30443110

bash-2.03#

None of the solution is working may be the command output formatting is not understood by everyone. The below output might help

bash-2.03$ df -t /fsystem | awk '{print $1}'

/fsystem

total:

bash-2.03$ df -t /fsystem | awk '{print $4}'

blocks

30443110

bash-2.03$ df -t /fsystem | awk '{print $5}'

14310982

files

bash-2.03$

Comment: Don't be `root` while experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

```
A="/fsystem (filer:/vol/volname/filesys): 3790340712 blocks 14310983 files total: 21616671840 blocks 30443110 files"
echo $A|awk '{print $10 - $5}'
```

16132127

Answer (score 0):

Some like this:

```
df -t /fsystem | awk -F"**" '{s=$6;f=$2" "$4;getline;print f,"("$2" - ",s")"}'
/fsystem filer:/vol/volname/filesys (30443110 -  14310983)
```

Comment: Output got was just    ( -  )

Comment: @Jotne, the ** was just part of the OP bolding the input to show what fields to capture. They didn't show up in the unformatted code.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: (Input example was changed by edit!) Try this command to ignore newlines within `awk`:

```
dt -t /fsystem  | awk 'BEGIN { RS = ""}; { C=$10 - $5; printf "%s %s\t%d\n",$1,$2,C}'
```

Example output:

```
/fsystem (filer:/vol/volname/filesys): 16132127
```

If you don't want all the introductory text, replace the `printf` portion of the command with however you want that part of the output to appear. For example:

```
printf "%s %d\n",$1,C
```

This gives:

```
/fsystem 16132127
```

Comment: Out got was /fsystem (filer:/vol/volname/filesys):        -14310983
total: 21616656968      0

Comment: You [or somebody] changed the example input string ;^) You would need to change the numbers of the $1, etc to match the positions of the correct fields. I'll try with the new example output... Do you want the `volname/filesys` in the output?

Answer (score 0):

More generally

```
df -t /ptsadmin |
awk -F '[ \t()]+' '/^total:/ { f=$3; next }
    { sub(/:$/,"",$2; d[NR]=$1" "$2; v[NR]=$5}
    END{ for(i=1; i<NR; ++i)
        print d[i] " " v[i]-f }'
```

Adding `()` to `FS` via the `-F` option takes care of removing them. Removing the final colon from `$2` is done by `sub()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS= '{gsub(/^\(|\):$/,"",$2); print $1, $2, ($10 - $5)}'
/fsystem filer:/vol/volname/filesys 16132127
```

The gsub() is necessary instead of setting FS in case you have (, ), or : in a name. This will not work if your names can contain spaces - it becomes a much tougher problem if you have that situation.